# Insert millions of rows in azure

Tags: azure-sql-database, sql-insert

im currently trying to insert about 100 millions of rows in a azure table. The problem is that each insert takes significantly more time than using a local database. Is there a way to manage this task in a more timely efficient manner?

Comment: Is your local database running off SSD?

Comment: No but it can, normally to insert 1 million rows takes like 10 minutes maybe. But a direct insert in sql azure takes a lot of time.

Comment: Are you using your local workstation to upload to Azure, or are you rolling data in from an Azure instance to its local SQL Server? Uploading remotely can be significantly slower.

Comment: im reading the row from a flat file and doing an insert into azure sql using C# .

Comment: Right, but are you reading the file locally and sending it over the network or what?

Comment: Yes, reading the file locally and insert over the network.

Comment: Like I said, that will be *crazy* slow. If you can upload that file to your SQL Server instance and import it there you'll probably find it's a lot faster.

Comment: yeah I figured. Any hint how to keep them in sync?

Comment: I'd recommend spinning up an VM instance in Azure to run your c# import to reduce the network latency between c# and your SQL Server instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing row-by-row inserts, it is going to be inefficient.  Two options to consider otherwise are using the ADO.Net BULK API in your c# code(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) or using the BCP utility to perform bulk inserts.   Both of these techniques will reduce round-trips to the database and avoid high-overhead log operations per-row.

Note that Azure SQL DB does not yet offer an option for uploading files to a server and importing from there.  (You can however move a flat file to an Azure Storage Blob, and execute a BCP or c# import program from an Azure VM if the latency of going directly from on-premises to Azure DB is still too long.)

Comment: in this instance, would it be better to compress flatfile before uploading to the blob, then decompressing it in the VM before BCPing to the azure SQL DB?